# Swipe To Choose Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to make view like below image... swipe to choose in ANDROID.

[image]

i found one library on github:

https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards

http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2014/04/tinder-app-like-control-with-animation.html

but in this lib there no option to show image **LIKED** or **NOPE** over CARD, just like showing in above image

can any one help me how to add these future in this library.

---

### EDITED 10-10-2014

---

I have create view group class inside that i have made **onTouchListener**

i am trying to get on **onClickListener** inside **onTouchListener**

**my issue is when i am touch on to left and right corner before click event some time its rotate view then click is work, so how i stop it when click is work 
another issue is when animation stop its also fire click event**

any one help me to improve below code?

```
this.imageContainerLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            private long startClickTime;
            private float x1;
            private float y1;
            private float x2;
            private float y2;
            private float _dx;
            private float _dy;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                Log.e("start x_cord-->" + x_cord, "y_cord--->" + y_cord);

                boolean defaultResult = v.onTouchEvent(event);

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x = (int) event.getRawX();
                    y = (int) event.getRawY();

                    this.startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance()
                            .getTimeInMillis();

                    x1 = event.getRawX();
                    y1 = event.getRawY();

                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    x_cord = (int) event.getRawX(); // Updated for more
                                                    // smoother animation.
                    y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                    Log.e("move x_cord-->" + x_cord, "y_cord--->" + y_cord);

                    CardView_new.this.setX(event.getRawX() - x);
                    CardView_new.this.setY(event.getRawY() - y);

                    if (x_cord >= screenCenter) {

                        /**
                         * rotate image 
                         * */


                            CardView_new.this
                                    .setRotation((float) (0.02454369260617026D * (x_cord - screenCenter)));

                        if (x_cord > (screenCenter + (screenCenter / 2))) {
                            buttonLike.setAlpha(1);
                            buttonDislike.setAlpha(0);
                            if (x_cord > (windowwidth - (screenCenter / 4))) {
                                Likes = 2;
                                moveIs = true;
                            } else {
                                Likes = 0;
                                moveIs = true;
                            }

                        } else {
                            Likes = 0;
                            buttonLike.setAlpha(0);
                            moveIs = false;
                        }
                        buttonDislike.setAlpha(0);
                    } else {
                        // rotate
                        /**
                         * rotate image 
                         * */


                            CardView_new.this
                                    .setRotation((float) (0.02454369260617026D * (x_cord - screenCenter)));


                        if (x_cord < (screenCenter / 2)) {
                            buttonDislike.setAlpha(1);
                            buttonLike.setAlpha(0);
                            if (x_cord < (screenCenter / 4)) {
                                Likes = 1;
                                moveIs = true;
                            } else {
                                Likes = 0;
                                moveIs = true;
                            }

                        } else {
                            Likes = 0;
                            buttonDislike.setAlpha(0);
                            moveIs = false;
                        }
                        buttonLike.setAlpha(0);
                    }

                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                    buttonDislike.setAlpha(0);
                    buttonLike.setAlpha(0);

                    x2 = event.getRawX();
                    y2 = event.getRawY();

                    _dx = x2 - x1;
                    _dy = y2 - y1;

                    long l = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
                            - this.startClickTime;
                    if ((l < 400L)
                            && distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) < MAX_CLICK_DISTANCE) {

                        Log.e("start Activity", "start activity");

                        CardView_new.this.setX(0);
                        CardView_new.this.setY(0);
                        CardView_new.this.setRotation(0);

                        if (moveIs == false) {
                            Intent i = new Intent((Activity) getContext(),
                                    DetailsActivity.class);

                            ((Activity) getContext()).startActivity(i);
                        }

                        return true;
                    } else if (Likes == 0) {
                        CardView_new.this.setX(0);
                        CardView_new.this.setY(0);
                        CardView_new.this.setRotation(0);
                        if (moveIs) {
                            moveIs = true;
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            moveIs = false;
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else if (Likes == 1) {
                        parentView.removeView(CardView_new.this);
                        CardView_new.this.mOnCardDimissedDelegate
                                .onLike(CardView_new.this);
                        Log.e("Likes==1", "Likes==1");
                        moveIs = true;
                        return true;
                    } else if (Likes == 2) {
                        parentView.removeView(CardView_new.this);

                        CardView_new.this.mOnCardDimissedDelegate
                                .onDislike(CardView_new.this);
                        Log.e("Likes==2", "Likes==2");
                        moveIs = true;
                        return true;
                    }

                default:
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just to confirm so the problem is not how to implement the view but how to save which image is liked or nope?

Comment: So you want a library that does everything for you, exactly to your specification, without modification? Good luck.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar My point is that you want something that does ALL of the work for you. Have you even attempted to add this feature to this library, or did you come straight to StackOverflow?

Comment: That's what it sounds like. I don't see any code posted from what you've already tried...

Comment: how can i import jar files for `CardContainer` & `SimpleCardStackAdapter` ? from where i can found the jar ?

Answer (score 13):

I have used this library: https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards

You need to modify it. After modification's, you will achieve it (See Screenshots below). Let me Explain.

**1.) std_card_inner.xml**

This xml is used to inflate the card row in the adapter class of the library. I have modified it to add two imageviews containing the like and dislike button and a textview to show the text "like" or "dislike" when user clicks any imageview.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/inner_relative"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/card_bg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="Title" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:background="@color/card_outline" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider_title"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@drawable/picture1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider_bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:background="@color/card_outline" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider_bottom"
        android:background="@color/card_bg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_sep_1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
        tools:text="This is the description, it is a long description, as you can see" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/btn_sep_1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_1"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_1"
        android:background="#ccc" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_sep_2"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/btn_sep_2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_1"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_2"
        android:background="#ccc" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/image"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/people" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/like_dislike"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/inner_relative"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_like" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dislike"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dislike" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/like_dislike_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/like_dislike"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**2.) SimpleCardStackAdapter.java**

This is the adapter for the cards. I have modified it to add the click listeners for both like and dislike imageview and a textview to show the text. When user clicks like button, i have added a boolean variable in the card model which stores the like/dislike value. True for like and false for dislike.

```
package com.andtinder.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.andtinder.R;
import com.andtinder.model.CardModel;

public final class SimpleCardStackAdapter extends CardStackAdapter {

    public SimpleCardStackAdapter(Context mContext) {
        super(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public View getCardView(int position, final CardModel model, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.std_card_inner, parent, false);
            assert convertView != null;
        }

        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageDrawable(model.getCardImageDrawable());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(model.getTitle());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText(model.getDescription());


        final TextView like_dislike_text = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_dislike_text));
        if(model.isLike())
            like_dislike_text.setText("Liked");
        else
            like_dislike_text.setText("DisLiked");

        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                model.setLike(true);
                like_dislike_text.setText("Liked");
            }
        });

        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dislike)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                model.setLike(false);
                like_dislike_text.setText("DisLiked");
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**3.) CardModel.java**

Finally, here I have added that boolean variable which stores the value for like/dislike.

```
private boolean isLike = false;
public boolean isLike() {
    return isLike;
}

public void setLike(boolean isLike) {
    this.isLike = isLike;
}
```

This is the final result:

**Screenshot 1**

[image]

**Screenshot 2**

[image]

Comment: Accordingly, you can call swipe listener's on the imageview's click listener

Comment: i want to show image of like & dislike on card when swipe... is it possible?

Comment: Like n dislike images are on card itself

Comment: how about button undo part?

Comment: how can i import jar files for `CardContainer` & `SimpleCardStackAdapter` ? from where i can found the jar ?

Comment: @rushankshah did you find it?

Comment: @RahulGupta : I just applying  ur solution . I'm stuck at one point , how can you set stack margin between two cards at the bottom for setting up numbers of card ?

Comment: @RahulGupta can you help me to solve my problem? In my case I load images from remote URL using ION library.`Ion.with(mImage)
                .load(url)
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<ImageView>() {
                    Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, ImageView result) { CardModel mCard = new CardModel("Title1", "Description goes here", mImage.getDrawable().getCurrent());
                            adapter.add(mCard);}` Image loading correctly,but swiping functionality not working

Comment: @RahulGupta can you please help me i want to do some orientation  changes ! like card swipe UP-DOWN instead of LEFT-RIGHT. How can i do in this library???

Comment: Is it possible to swipe up? How to modify the CardContainer.java, in such case? Please help

Answer (score 4):

With the help of [Swipecard](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) library, i made UI like tinder swipe card animation.

You can download example [here](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-swipe-cards-like-tinder-app/), where i explained step by step there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How to get the position of the first card,second card like that .let me know? based on the the card position. for eg: in listview item position. Like wise is there any possibility to get a card position from first card to last card while swiping

Answer (score 2):

I got a result for **like** and **unlike** button to flip images to **left** and **right**.

Use this [Swipe Cards like tinder swipe Sample](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-swipe-cards-like-tinder-app/).

**MainActivity.java:**

Inside the `MyAppAdapter getView()` method,add these below codes:

```
 viewHolder.likeImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            flipMethodRight(80.00f);

        }
    });

    viewHolder.unlikeImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            flipMethodLeft(-80.00f);

        }
    });
```

Add these below codes outside of `MyAppAdapter class`:

```
 void flipMethodRight(float scrollProgressPercent) {


        flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectRight();

        View view = flingContainer.getSelectedView();
        view.findViewById(R.id.background).setAlpha(0);

        view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_left_indicator).setAlpha(scrollProgressPercent > 0 ? scrollProgressPercent : 0);

    }

    void flipMethodLeft(float scrollProgressPercent) {


        flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectLeft();

        View view = flingContainer.getSelectedView();
        view.findViewById(R.id.background).setAlpha(0);
        view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_right_indicator).setAlpha(scrollProgressPercent < 0 ? -scrollProgressPercent : 0);


    }
```

Thanks to @nirav kalola for this Sample.

Answer (score 1):

Use a viewpager, and change the OnPageChangeListener.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

Just overload the onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) method. The int is related to the item's index on the adapter, so you can use that to identify the image.

Example:

```
_viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
            System.out.println("SWIPING!!!!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            System.out.println("SELECTED!!!!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
            System.out.println("CHANGED!!!!");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create four new global float variable x_cord, y_cord, x_cordIn & y_cordIn.

```
ainerLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    private long startClickTime;
    private float x1;
    private float y1;
    private float x2;
    private float y2;
    private float _dx;
    private float _dy;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        boolean defaultResult = v.onTouchEvent(event);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x_cord = x_cordIn = event.getRawX();
                y_cord = y_cordIn = event.getRawY();

                x1 = (int) event.getRawX();
                y1 = (int) event.getRawY();

                this.startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x_cord = event.getRawX();
                y_cord = event.getRawY();

                float xPos = myRelView.getX() - (x_cordIn - x_cord);
                float yPos = myRelView.getY() - (y_cordIn - y_cord);

                CardView_new.this.setX(xPos);
                CardView_new.this.setY(yPos);

                if (x_cord >= screenCenter) {

                    /**
                     * rotate image 
                     * */
                    CardView_new.this.setRotation((float) (xPos * (Math.PI / 32)));

                    if (x_cord > (screenCenter + (screenCenter / 2))) {
                        buttonLike.setAlpha(1);
                        buttonDislike.setAlpha(0);
                        if (x_cord > (windowwidth - (screenCenter / 4))) {
                            Likes = 2;
                            moveIs = true;
                        } else {
                            Likes = 0;
                            moveIs = true;
                        }

                    } else {
                        Likes = 0;
                        buttonLike.setAlpha(0);
                        moveIs = false;
                    }
                    buttonDislike.setAlpha(0);
                } else {
                    // rotate
                    /**
                     * rotate image 
                     * */

                    CardView_new.this.setRotation((float) (xPos * (Math.PI / 32)));

                    if (x_cord < (screenCenter / 2)) {
                        buttonDislike.setAlpha(1);
                        buttonLike.setAlpha(0);
                        if (x_cord < (screenCenter / 4)) {
                            Likes = 1;
                            moveIs = true;
                        } else {
                            Likes = 0;
                            moveIs = true;
                        }

                    } else {
                        Likes = 0;
                        buttonDislike.setAlpha(0);
                        moveIs = false;
                    }
                    buttonLike.setAlpha(0);
                }

                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                buttonDislike.setAlpha(0);
                buttonLike.setAlpha(0);

                x2 = event.getRawX();
                y2 = event.getRawY();

                _dx = x2 - x1;
                _dy = y2 - y1;

                long l = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
                        - this.startClickTime;
                if ((l < 400L)
                        && distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) < MAX_CLICK_DISTANCE) {

                    Log.e("start Activity", "start activity");

                    CardView_new.this.setX(0);
                    CardView_new.this.setY(0);
                    CardView_new.this.setRotation(0);

                    if (moveIs == false) {
                        Intent i = new Intent((Activity) getContext(),
                                DetailsActivity.class);

                        ((Activity) getContext()).startActivity(i);
                    }

                    return true;
                } else if (Likes == 0) {
                    CardView_new.this.setX(0);
                    CardView_new.this.setY(0);
                    CardView_new.this.setRotation(0);
                    if (moveIs) {
                        moveIs = true;
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        moveIs = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (Likes == 1) {
                    parentView.removeView(CardView_new.this);
                    CardView_new.this.mOnCardDimissedDelegate
                            .onLike(CardView_new.this);
                    Log.e("Likes==1", "Likes==1");
                    moveIs = true;
                    return true;
                } else if (Likes == 2) {
                    parentView.removeView(CardView_new.this);

                    CardView_new.this.mOnCardDimissedDelegate
                            .onDislike(CardView_new.this);
                    Log.e("Likes==2", "Likes==2");
                    moveIs = true;
                    return true;
                }

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [RossDeckView](https://github.com/diogobernardino/RossDeckView), a lite one allowing to swipe in whatever direction you would like.

[image]