# Android RecyclerView with CardView - show cards in a stack-like (not a list)

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to use the `RecyclerView` which is in the Android support v7 library to display a bunch of `CardViews` (which is also in the v7 support library), but instead of showing them on a list (in which I can scroll up/down) I want to show them as a stack (like card stack).

Does anyone know how I can achieve this behavior?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you looking for something like the recents screen on Android Lollipop?

Comment: im not sure what screens you are talking about . but i want a tinder like card stack

Comment: Any Screenshot Available?

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25967748

Comment: Are you looking for this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83rWN7qtdJU)?

Comment: do you want to be this done only with RecyclerView?? or any other libraries fine??

Comment: I would use a ViewPager for this use case

Comment: You can try [FlippableStackView](https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView) which uses `ViewPager`. You can very well change the transformer according to your need. In this case it shrinks the top view to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [CardsUI-for-Android](https://github.com/Androguide/cardsui-for-android)

### CardsUI

> An open source library offering the popular Google Now & Google Play
>   cards views, additionnal features, view recycling and an optional
>   Model-View-Controller structure.

### Google Play Cards

This new type of card based on the new Google play design are highly customization.

**The parameters include:**

- Title text (String)
- Description text (String)
- Title color (String)
- Stripe color (String)
- Menu overflow (Boolean)
- Touch feedback on click (Boolean)

**Here is an example:**

```
mCardView.addCard(new MyPlayCard(
        "Different Colors for Title & Stripe", 
        "You can set any color for the title and any other color for the left stripe", 
        "#f2a400", "#9d36d0", true, false));
```

[See Docs for More...](https://github.com/Androguide/cardsui-for-android#google-play-cards)

May it will be useful to you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I have added more description. Thank you for your suggestion.