# how to make multiple card above each other and remove each card when scroll horizental?

Tags: android, slideshow, slidetoggle, android-cardview

how to make multiple card above each other and remove each card when scroll horizontal and each card display different content like new update in linked app
like his [image]

Comment: Check this : <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967748/swipe-to-choose-android>

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to make them look stacked like that but here is a guide to implement the horizontal swipe 
http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator/