# How to create a stack-like view in android

Tags: android

[image: sample image]

As you can see from the image , each card is stacked on top of each other. I am planning on using fragments for each card but I am wondering how to go about giving it the stacked card effect.

It would be great if someone could give me a pointer to help figure this out.

Also, feel free to ask for anything if what I have said is not clear enough.

Comment: Did you try just googling? There's multiple libraries on github.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967748/swipe-to-choose-android

Comment: It wasnt finding the library but why that library was working which I couldnt figure out. I am relatively new to Java and Android, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At first hist try to search sonme libraries in net. There are a lot of them. Search on `Android-Arsenal` or `GitHub` with keywords:"tinder", "stack", "deck", etc.

As for me, http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3079 this one is one of the best.

Comment: Thank you ! But finding libraries is not what i wanted but a logic on how the said library was working