# Show image on swipe of cardview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, swipe

My app contains card views which the user can swipe left and right in order to post something to the server (like Google Inbox for example).

I'm trying to show an image while swiping but it works only when swiping to the right.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my layout of a single card:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/clipSwipeBackgroundLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dislikeBackground"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clipSwipeImageLeft"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_dontlike"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/clipSwipeBackgroundRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/snoozeBackground"
        tools:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_snooze"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/recLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">
```

This is my code that shows the background color and image on swipe

```
private void drawBackground(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, int actionState)
            {
                if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE)
                {
                    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point screenSize = new Point();
                    display.getSize(screenSize);

                    final View backgroundViewRight = ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).mSwipeBackgroundRight;
                    final View backgroundViewLeft = ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).mSwipeBackgroundLeft;

                    // Swiping Right
                    if (dX > 0)
                    {
                        Log.d("right is", Integer.toString((int)Math.max(dX, 0)));
                        backgroundViewRight.setRight((int) Math.max(dX, 0));
                        backgroundViewRight.setLeft(0);

                        backgroundViewLeft.setRight(0);
                        backgroundViewLeft.setLeft(0);
                    }
                    // Swiping Left
                    else
                    {
                        // screenSize.x is the width of the screen
                        Log.d("left is", Integer.toString((int)(screenSize.x + dX)));
                        backgroundViewLeft.setRight(screenSize.x);
                        backgroundViewLeft.setLeft((int)(screenSize.x + dX)); 
                        backgroundViewRight.setRight(0);
                        backgroundViewRight.setLeft(0);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Edit 1:
Example of the missing image (and the one on the other side)
[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967748/swipe-to-choose-android This might help you

Comment: There are many other third party libraries https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards  ...  
https://github.com/RobertFischer/Gradle-License-Report  ....
http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-swipe-cards-like-tinder-app/

Comment: I was hoping that someone can fix my code easily. the tinder like libraries don't support adding the background image. maybe this one https://github.com/wdullaer/SwipeActionAdapter

Comment: check dX values on left and right swipes

Comment: The dX seems to be find. The background (with its color) appears just right but the image is missing