# How to implement swipe card functionality?

Tags: android

I want to implement card swipe functionality like left & right card swipe.

I have followed following examples links

1. https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/222
2. https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards
3. http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2014/04/tinder-app-like-control-with-animation.html
4. [Swipe To Choose Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25967748/5505915)
5. https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2970
6. https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack

I want to implement cards like below image,

[image]

Here the top card is visible to user to 100% while the two other cards are partially visible.

User can swipe left or right way.

Can any one help me to implement such requirements ?

Comment: You might want to show us what you have tried in code if you need solutions! yes, you have followed few examples but it is unclear how far you have progressed and what precisely you want.

Comment: @Ashwinkumar, I have tried the second option. I also tried to customized it. But the output I want is as I described in the image above.

Comment: @Ashwinkumar, I have also tried this example https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack